# Reading text inbetween tag

Tags: jquery

I am using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/). One of the column have hyperlink text. I am getting this text as

```
var ColText = myTable.fnGetData(0,5);
```

which is like

```
<a href="" onClick="return someFunction(someParam)">TextToRead</a>
```

Now I am trying to get text "TextToRead". So my question is can I use any jQuery to get this or I have to use regular expression or any other options. Please suggest.

Comment: `$(selector).text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ColText` is HTML `String`, as you've said it is, then just parse it with jQuery.

```
console.log($(ColText).text()); // TextToRead
```

`$(ColText)` returns a jQuery `DOM` object, which has `text` method, which gets what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Superman/5bpLas40/).

```
var txt = $('a').text();
console.log(txt);
```